# Extracting each word out of a string without getting an extra empty value at the end

Tags: javascript, split

I'm trying to split all the words out of my string, without getting an extra empty value in it. My current attempt is this.

```
var words = "This is a test!";
var arr = words.split(/\W+/);
print(arr);
```

The output is `This, is, a, test,` where I was expecting `This, is, a, test`. This is clearly due to the ! at the end of my string.

I'd like to be able to insert strings like `This is a test` and `This is a test!` into my method, but I would like the same response of `This, is, a, test` from both of these strings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not `words.split(/\s+/);` ??

Comment: Because it would give me test! as one of my responses, in which case I only want the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you should use `.match()` with `g` flag instead of `.split()`.

```js
var words = "This is a test!";
var arr = words.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: A subtle difference worth mentioning is the `g` flag, without which only one match would be given.

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting on `\W` which will matches any non word character and will also match the `!` so there will be a split there leaving an empty entry.

You could remove that empty entry using filter:

```js
let strings = [
  "This is a test!",
  "This is a test"
].map(s => s.split(/\W+/).filter(Boolean));
console.log(strings);
```

Comment: This was very good and answered my question, but I decided to use match as it better suited my needs. I appreciate your response though!

Comment: @Kenneth That is perfectly ok, you can always accept ans answer and upvote the answers that have been proven helpful to you